# PrimeFaces Use FileDownload Inside Form

Tags: validation, primefaces, download

I'm using PrimeFaces as the web technology in my project. I have a registration form, by that the user registers himself. In that form, the user can also attach some documents. There is no problem so far. But when the user filled the form and attached some documents, the user can check the attachment by downloading them. To provide downloading the files, I used fileDownload with commandButton. 
It works fine, but the problem is that when the use wants to download the attached files, the form is validated! So if any field in the form is not validated, the user can't download any file! 
I want to provide the opportunity for the user, so that he can first attach the document and check them before filling the form's fields.
I'm very appreciated it if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
immediate="true"
```

as the attribute for the commandButton, inside that you are using fileDownload.
For more information about immediate [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541829/pcommandbutton-with-immediate-true).