# p:commandButton with immediate=true

Tags: jsf-2

What action is taken when I declare `immediate="true"` in command button? The documentation says

> Boolean value that determines the phaseId of the action event, when true actions are processed at "Apply Request Values", when false at "Invoke Application" phase.

However, I don't understand it. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: See BalusC's title: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSF lifecycle contains 6 phases, which are:

1. Restore view
2. Apply request values
3. Process validations
4. Update model values
5. Invoke application
6. Render response

If a command button has `immediate="true"`, then the phases 'Process validations' and 'Update model values' are skipped. Therefore, convertions and validations are not processed and attributes in managed bean are not updated.

However, if a UIInput in the form also has immediate="true", then its value will be converted, validated and updated in managed bean, because it will happen in 'Apply request values' phase.

One example of when you might use a button with immediate="true" is the case of a 'Cancel' button.

Comment: you are welcome @Ponni Maran. like any input, if it has immediate="true", the validation (if any) will happen in 'Apply request values phase', and its value will be sent to the managed bean in that phase too.

Comment: Fine Damian, I did select/unselect all based on single select. in the p:dialog dataTable. in the dialog close button im using immediate="true" when its first time the dialog open its works properly after close and reopen the dialog list checkboxes have the previous selected value not update the new value by selecting the single select checkbox

Comment: Based on your words its update the bean value. but after once its updated it not  able to change

Comment: let me see if I understand. you open the dialog, which shows the selected options in the managed bean. then you change them, but click "Close" (with immediate=true). then you reopen and the changed values are displayed? this doesn't mean changes were applied to the bean. to show again bean values, you should update the dialog via ajax (maybe in the close button). this will bring the values from the bean again

Comment: thanks its working fine. i did understand the difference b/w immediate in commandbutton & input field

Comment: So, the documentation is missing the commandButton behavior of the 'immediate' attribute as well. Thanks for posting it so clearly.